# How can I match a template with the original image by SURF?

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision, surf, object-detection

Recently, I have worked with robotics project; my robot can detect the object by its colour but I found that not good enough for different object. Therefore, I want the robot SURF the image on real time to find the target object that will be defined using its template.

Unfortunately, I don’t know how to match the key points of the template with its image in the image.

Answer (score 1):

There is a very good example to know how to use SURF in the sample directory in your OpenCV directory: OpenCV/samples/c/find_obj.cpp

You need to use the SURF descriptors (see lines 245-255)

```
CvSeq *objectKeypoints = 0, *objectDescriptors = 0;
CvSURFParams params = cvSURFParams(500, 1);
cvExtractSURF(object, 0, &objectKeypoints, &objectDescriptors, storage, params);
```

You should read the descriptors with a CvSeqReader:

```
CvSeqReader reader;
cvStartReadSeq(descriptors, &reader, 0);
```

Do the same thing with scene and use the two descriptors in NN search to find the match between them.
One again, the sample given by OpenCV should help you a lot :)

Comment: Thanks alots for your answer, I'm interesting to determine the object's location in the image so could you tell the codes that can do that and also I try using the code that you told me can find in opencv sample but it is not working unless I comment these two functions cv::flann::Index flann_index(m_image, cv::flann::KDTreeIndexParams(4)); // using 4 randomized kdtrees flann_index.knnSearch(m_object, m_indices, m_dists, 2, cv::flann::SearchParams(64) ); // maximum number of leafs checked so could you tell me why please?

Comment: I don't really get your question. Can you reformat your code you are talking about and clearify what do you mean by "it is not working". The sample or your code is not working?